# How to extract only datein ddmmyy format from a timestamp

Tags: python

I tried using lambda function but i am not sure how to extract the date in a specific format from it. I extracted day, month and year separately using lambda function and then combining the results of all separately and putting it into a dataframe. But this is not looking like a good approach. I need date in ddmmyy format from the time stamp `"5/29/2020  12:00:00 AM".`

```
df_obj['Date only'] = df_obj['Date only'].apply(lambda x: x.day)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = "5/29/2020 12:00:00 AM"
datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(
    timestamp, "%m/%d/%Y  %I:%M:%S %p"
)  # parsing string to datetime object
print(
    datetime_obj.strftime("%d%m%Y")
)  # converting datetime object to required string format
```

**Output:**

```
29052020
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution I tried using this solution, its working for a single value but when I am trying to pass dataframe as a input then it is throwing error message "TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Timestamp" and when I am entering the dataframe after type casting into string then I am getting different error.

Answer (score 0):

Date and time is represented may be different in different places, organizations etc. It's more common to use mm/dd/yyyy in the US, whereas dd/mm/yyyy is more common in the UK.

Python has **strftime()** and **strptime()** methods to handle this.

```
from datetime import datetime

# current date and time
now = datetime.now()

t = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print("time:", t)

s1 = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
# mm/dd/YY H:M:S format
print("s1:", s1)

s2 = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
# dd/mm/YY H:M:S format
print("s2:", s2)
```

time: 04:34:52
s1: 12/26/2018, 04:34:52
s2: 26/12/2018, 04:34:52

The **strptime()** method creates a datetime object from a given string (representing date and time).

```
from datetime import datetime

date_string = "21 June, 2018"
print("date_string =", date_string)

date_object = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%d %B, %Y")
print("date_object =", date_object)
```

date_string = 21 June, 2018
date_object = 2018-06-21 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

First of all convert the string into datetime object using `datetime` library.
Use this code snippet for your string to convert into datetime object.

```py
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.strptime("21/11/06 16:30", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
```

After this to extract date,month and year in required format you can use formatters like %d,%m,%y etc.,For the required format here i.e.,`ddmmyyyy`, one can use the string `"{0:%d}{0:%m}{0:%y}".format(dt)` to assign to any object wherever needed without using any lambda functions.

For example:

`dateframe_col={0:%d}{0:%m}{0:%y}".format(dt)`

You can check [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) for more information about date and time manipulations in python.